# Existence of d-regular subgraphs in a k-regular graph

Tags: graphs

The claim is as follows:
Let's say we have a $k$-regular simple undirected graph $G$ on $n$ vertices. Then, does $G$ then always have a $d$-factor for all $d$ satisfying $1 \le d \lt k$ and $dn$ being even.

I think its true, since we can construct a

- $k+1$-regular graph from $G$ by adding $\frac{n}{2}$ edges for even $n$ or
- $k+2$-regular graph from $G$ by adding $n$ edges for odd $n$

And the converse for the above.
We can construct a $k$-regular graph on $n$ vertices by

- removing $\frac{n}{2}$ edges from a $k+1$-regular graph for even $n$.
- removing $n$ edges from a $k+2$-regular graph for odd $n$.

Hence, using the converse argument, we can say that the original claim is true, since from a $k$-regular graph $G$ we can construct

- $1$-factor, $2$-factor, ... $k-1$-factor for even $n$ or
- $2$-factor, $4$-factor, ... $k-2$-factor for odd $n$

Is my argument correct or is there any flaw in this argument?

Comment: *Hence, the opposite should also be true.* Why? There are a lot of statements of the type $A \Rightarrow B$ in which the converse $B \Rightarrow A$ is false. For example, if $a$ is positive then so is $a^2$, but the converse doesn't hold.

Comment: Your claim is also not true, since you need the graph to be simple. Consider what happens if $G$ is the complete graph.

Comment: Oh I'm really sorry. I've been ambiguous about whats the opposite of what. Let me edit the question.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus I have edited the question. Have a look now.

Comment: Your argument doesn’t work. I already gave you a counterexample.

Comment: This is very intriguing and counterintuitive. I've always taken it for granted that a graph on even vertices always has a perfect matching. Thank you very much!

Comment: I think this question needs another edit, because you actually asking about d-factors, right? Please see our conversation with @YuvalFilmus. Also: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_factorization

Comment: @HEKTO You're right. $d$-factor is the more appropriate term.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your conjecture is false. There are regular graphs with an even number of vertices yet without a 1-regular subgraph. See [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/520203/k-regular-simple-graph-without-1-factor) on [Mathematics](https://math.stackexchange.com).

The complement of such a graph gives a counterexample to your claim that you can always add a perfect matching to increase the regularity (when the number of vertices is even).

In the bipartite case, however, your conjecture is true. Any $k$-regular bipartite graph can be decomposed into $k$ perfect matchings. This follows from Hall's theorem.

Comment: The question you refer to is about 1-factors... The OP question is about subgraphs - more general case

Comment: @HEKTO A $d$-factor is a $d$-regular subgraph (on the same set of vertices). That's the definition.

Comment: Subgraphs can have less vertices

Comment: Factors have the same vertex set

Comment: Reading the post, it seems clear that the OP is after subgraphs obtained just by removing edges. For example, otherwise there is no reason to restrict to even $dn$ (I'll let you figure out some other hints).